# Smaller amounts of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I reduce the amount of my JavaScript code in this example? I would like to have DRY code.

I would like the to know what I need to do in order not to repeat myself with the EventListeners.

Please find the code down here. First JavaScript, then CSS, then HTML.

```js
var firstLi = document.querySelector("#one");
var secondLi = document.querySelector("#two");
var thirdLi = document.querySelector("#three");

firstLi.addEventListener("click", done);
secondLi.addEventListener("click", done);
thirdLi.addEventListener("click", done);

firstLi.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
secondLi.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
thirdLi.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);

firstLi.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut);
secondLi.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut);
thirdLi.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut);

function done() {
  this.classList.toggle("greyout");
}

function hover() {
  this.classList.add("hover");
}

function hoverOut() {
  this.classList.remove("hover");
}
```

```css
.hover {
  color: green;
}

.greyout {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>to do's</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li id="one">One</li>
      <li id="two">Two</li>
      <li id="three">Three</li>
    </ul>

  <script src="todo.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know you can get the same result by using CSS's `:hover` selector, right?

Comment: And for the click handler, one might consider [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) - useful if the set of clickable items changes over time and you don't want to manage event listeners each time you insert/remove an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Loops](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM) and [functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html) are the usual ways to apply the same operations to multiple values.

Put the elements in an array and iterator over it:

```
var elements = [firstLi, /*...*/];

elements.forEach(function(element) {
   element.addEventListener(/*...*/);
   // ...
});
```

But as mentioned in the comments, hover effects can be achieved without any JavaScript, using the `:hover` CSS selector:

```
li:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thx, and yes I know that is possible just by using CSS. That's just some JavaScript practise.

Comment: You _could_ use a loop, but it seems like in this case it would make more sense to use a delegate event listener. It is good generic advice though for reducing the amount of repeated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event delegation and add one event listener on list:

```js
var list = document.querySelector("ul");
list.addEventListener("click", done);

function done(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle("greyout");
  }
}
```

```css
li:hover {
  color: green;
}

.greyout {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>to do's</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li id="one">One</li>
      <li id="two">Two</li>
      <li id="three">Three</li>
    </ul>

  <script src="todo.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this you also wouldn't need to have ids for the `li` elements (unless you'll need them for something else later).

Answer (score 0):

```
function multipleHandler(element, events, handler){
        for(var iloop=0; iloop< events.length; iloop++){
           element.addEventListener(events[iloop], (function handlerFn(){
              return handler[iloop];
           })() );
        }
}
```